# verilog $timeformat not properly evaluated in modelsim batch mode (does not work :(

Tags: verilog, modelsim, time-format

In my verilog testbench I'm using `timescale 1 ns / 1 ns` and `$timeformat` like this:

```
initial $timeformat(-3 , 6, " ms", 14);
```

When running in GUI mode (ModelSim), debug prompt is as expected, e.g.:

```
#    0.000000 ms          WDOG : *** tc_can_init_check alive: simulation break at 0.200000 ms
#    0.000225 ms       INFO : ############################################
#    0.000225 ms       INFO : #
#    0.000225 ms       INFO : # starting test sequence
#    0.000225 ms       INFO : #
#    0.000225 ms       INFO : ############################################
```

Note that time format of `simulation break at 0.200000 ms` in first line is as expected, as well as format of timestamp in beginning of each line (`0.000225 ms` meaning 225 nano second, which corresponds to ``timescale).

Now, when running ModelSim in batch mode it seems that `$timeformat` is not properly considered any more:

```
#    0.000000 ms          WDOG : *** tc_can_init_check alive: simulation break at 0.200000 ms
#  224.999000 ms       INFO : ############################################
#  224.999000 ms       INFO : #
#  224.999000 ms       INFO : # starting test sequence
#  224.999000 ms       INFO : #
#  224.999000 ms       INFO : ############################################
```

Note that formatting of `simulation break at 0.200000 ms` in first line is still as expected, but format of timestamp in beginning of each line is wrong ! (`224.999000 ms` which is basically the correct time but shifted by 6 decimals - i.e. time is displayed in nano seconds).

**It seems to me that `$timeformat` becomes ignored when** (ModelSim) **running in batch mode.**

Why ?! 
And how to overcome this ??

The only difference between these two cases that I can spot is GUI mode vs. batch mode:

- Is there any switch to consider ?
- Is there any compile (order) issue that could cause such effects ?
- Maybe, is there any known tool issue ??

Anybody who could give me a hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanx dave_59 for reminding me to divide & conquer :)

After implementing your example and getting same (bad) results within my environment, I created a completely independend test environemnt from scratch: In this new environemnt everything worked as expected !

So I tried to isolate root cause by stepwise commenting sections in my script set.

It finally turns out that `sim.do` file is causing the problem. There it reads, regardless of batch or GUI mode:

```
run 1 ns
restart -f
run -all
```

The reason for this sequence is to speed up simulation time: Simulation seems to run faster after you've issued a `restart` command. I can't explain it, but this is what I had found out in the very beginning. So this sequence is in there since then ;)

Now I have modified it like this:

```
if [batch_mode] {
  run -all
} else {
  run 1 ns
  restart -f
  run -all
}
```

**=> With this modication all problems are gone  !**

Maybe ModelSim `restart` command behaves slightly different if in batch rather than in GUI mode ?

Comment: remember to accept the good answer next time and to modify your original post with the post-answer findings instead of making a reply to your original post : )

Answer (score 0):

A simple test with single file will demonstrated that the problem is not with $timeformat

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns
module top;
   initial begin
      $timeformat(-3 , 6, " ms", 14);
      #225000;
      $display("time : %t",$realtime);
   end
endmodule
```

Try running the above in GUI and in batch and see if there is a difference. Otherwise you'll need to show us the exact command line you are using.

Comment: I've created such module as you describe and added it to my compile list.
Then I've modified the script that invokes simulator to use `top` instead of my testbench.
The result is as same as before.
I provide both log files where you can also find command line being executed.

Comment: **GUI mode:**
`# vsim ../work.top -L cycloneive_ver -L altera_mf_ver -L altera_lnsim_ver -L altera_ver -L lpm_ver -logfile tc_can_init_check.log -wlf tc_can_init_check.wlf -f C:/Users/georgm/Desktop/FOD/trunk/3_design/4_simulation/tc_can_init_check/options -do "sim.do" 
# Start time: 07:19:29 on Jun 20,2018
# Loading ../work.top
# do sim.do
# time :    0.225000 ms
# 5_sim_gui - done
# 5_sim_prep - done
# 7_sim_tc - done`

Comment: **Batch mode:**
`# vsim ../work.top -L cycloneive_ver -L altera_mf_ver -L altera_lnsim_ver -L altera_ver -L lpm_ver -batch -logfile tc_can_init_check.log -wlf tc_can_init_check.wlf "+TCNAME=tc_can_init_check" -do "sim.do" 
# Start time: 07:17:51 on Jun 20,2018
# Loading ../work.top
# 
# do sim.do
# time : 225000.000000 ms
# End time: 07:17:52 on Jun 20,2018, Elapsed time: 0:00:01
# Errors: 0, Warnings: 0`

Comment: There are two files `options` and `sim.do` mentioned.
They are identical in batch and GUI mode.
I put theirs content here for reference.
**options**
`+TCNAME=tc_can_init_check`
**sim.do**
`if [batch_mode] {
   do log.do
} else {
  do log.do
  do wave.do
}

run 1 ns
restart -f
run -all

if [batch_mode] {
   quit -f
}`